# python почта как отправить фото на почту?

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, smtplib

помогите пожалуйста отправить фото на почту gmail

Comment: Mime multipart собирай

Comment: @eri а можно подробнее?

Comment: http://codius.ru/articles/Python_%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA_%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%BE_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%82%D1%83 , вам стоило немного поискать в интернете, это все делаеться за 5 секунд

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как пример отправки сообщения с вложением:

```py
import smtplib
import os

from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEBase
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.header import Header

# Данные письма
mail_from = "from@gmail.com"  # отправитель
mail_to = "to@gmail.com"  # получатель
mail_text = "Тестовое письмо!nПослано из python"  # текст письма
mail_subj = "Тестовое письмо"  # заголовок письма
mail_coding = "windows-1251"
attach_file = ""  # ["D:\\test.txt", "D:\\test2.txt"] # прикрепляемый файл

# Параметры SMTP-сервера
smtp_server = "smtp.gmail.com"
smtp_port = 587
smtp_user = "from@gmail.com"  # пользователь smtp
smtp_pwd = "pass"  # пароль smtp

# Формирование сообщения
multi_msg = MIMEMultipart()
multi_msg["From"] = Header(mail_from, mail_coding)
multi_msg["To"] = Header(mail_to, mail_coding)
multi_msg["Subject"] = Header(mail_subj, mail_coding)

msg = MIMEText(mail_text.encode("cp1251"), "plain", mail_coding)
msg.set_charset(mail_coding)
multi_msg.attach(msg)

# Прикрепляем файл
for add_file in attach_file:
    if os.path.exists(add_file) and os.path.isfile(add_file):
        file = open(add_file, "rb")
        attachment = MIMEBase("application", "octet-stream")
        attachment.set_payload(file.read())
        email.encoders.encode_base64(attachment)
        file.close()
        only_name_attach = Header(os.path.basename(add_file), mail_coding)
        attachment.add_header("Content-Disposition",
                              'attachment; filename="%s"' % only_name_attach)
        multi_msg.attach(attachment)
    else:
        if add_file.lstrip() != "":
            print("Файл для атача не найден - " + add_file)

# Отправка
smtp = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server, smtp_port)
smtp.ehlo()
smtp.starttls()
smtp.ehlo()
smtp.login(smtp_user, smtp_pwd)
smtp.sendmail(mail_from, mail_to, multi_msg.as_string())
smtp.quit()
```